# PHP: Creating a new file / page on submit

Tags: php, mysqli, forum

So, I'm a little new to PHP and was wondering if someone could please give me a **simple yet indepth** answer on the problem I am having..

Lets take a forum like such for example. When a user creates a new thread how does the site create a new page (their thread)? Usually, the URL will end up looking like http://www.(sitename).com/forum/77375 <- Post ID I assume. How would I make such a thing?

I have a site which requires users to submit an article and currently I have made it so the article information is sent to a database. Now I need to make it so a new page is made with a unique URL with their article on it.

I am using PHP with MySqli
- Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can easily achieve this using .htaccess.

Comment: Currently I have not tried anything, I have no idea how to approach such a task nor know what exactly to search, sorry :( Thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 1):

When you see SEO friendly URL like that, the site isn't (or at least shouldn't) be making an actually file with that post id.  The site is doing a url rewrite.  Basically it will take a URL such as `http://www.sitename.com/forum` and regardless of what comes after that, always load the same file (lets say it's called `forum.php`.  It will then take the rest of the url, and change that into a query string.

So it will basically rewrite:

```
http://www.sitename.com/forum/123456
```

to be:

```
http://www.sitename.com/forum.php?thread_id=123456
```

Which the forum.php file can then get the data from the query string and know to pull the forum posts for the thread with the id of `123456`

Here's a post with some more info:
[URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
     RewriteEngine on

    # Not for real file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # for category-1/ and all like xxxxx-xxx-nnn
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+-\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=category&category_name=$1 [L]

    # for contact/ or about/ or other/
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

so you can get something like as below :

> http://www.example.com/index.php?page=Movie&movie_name=anyMovie
>   - > http://www.example.com/anyMovie/

Comment: This answer is bit too cryptic imho